# Meshes loaded via Assimp look distorted

Tags: c++, direct3d, assimp

So I'm trying to load and render mesh with assimp and DirectX11.(Im loosely following tutorials on youtube) The problem is that it looks weird and distorted. I've checked my meshes - blender and assimp viewer load them correctly.
Results of rendering suzanne from obj file:
[Suzanne from obj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW6Dq.png)

It looks kinda like the index buffer is wrong but i do not see a mistake when propagating it;
Mesh loading code:

```
struct Vertex
{
   struct
   {
       float x;
       float y;
       float z;
   }Position;

};
```

```
Model::Model(const std::string & path)
    {
        Ref<Zephyr::VertexShader> VertexShader = Zephyr::VertexShader::Create("MinimalShaders.hlsl", "VertexShaderMain");

        AddBindable(VertexShader);

        AddBindable(Zephyr::PixelShader::Create("MinimalShaders.hlsl", "PixelShaderMain"));

        AddBindable(Zephyr::Topology::Create(Zephyr::Topology::TopologyType::TriangleList));

        std::vector<Zephyr::InputLayout::InputLayoutElement> InputLayout =
        {
            {"Position",Zephyr::InputLayout::InputDataType::Float3}
        };

        AddBindable(Zephyr::InputLayout::Create(InputLayout, VertexShader));

        Assimp::Importer Imp;
        auto model = Imp.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_Triangulate);

        const auto Mesh = model->mMeshes[0];

        std::vector<Vertex> Vertices;
        Vertices.reserve(Mesh->mNumVertices);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
        {
            Vertex buf;
            buf.Position = { Mesh->mVertices[i].x,Mesh->mVertices[i].y ,Mesh->mVertices[i].z };
            Vertices.push_back(buf);
        }

        std::vector<unsigned short> Indices;
        Indices.reserve(Mesh->mNumFaces * 3);
        

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
        {
            const auto & face = Mesh->mFaces[i];

            if (face.mNumIndices != 3)
            {
                Zephyr::Log::Error("More than 3 indices per face ?!"); continue;
            }
                
            Indices.push_back(face.mIndices[0]);
            Indices.push_back(face.mIndices[1]);
            Indices.push_back(face.mIndices[2]);
        }

        AddBindable(Zephyr::VertexBuffer::Create(Vertices));
        BindIndexBuffer(Zephyr::IndexBuffer::Create(Indices));

    }
```

My shaders are pretty minimal to

```
cbuffer CBuff
{
    matrix transform;
};

float4 VertexShaderMain(float3 position : Position) : SV_POSITION
{
    return mul(float4(position, 1.0), transform);

}

float4 PixelShaderMain() : SV_TARGET
{
  return float4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

My pipeline renders correctly, f. ex. cubes which are hard coded, but when i try to load cube from file this happens:
[distorted cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utXr0.png)

Assimp opens the file and loads the correct number of vertices. Also number of indices seems to be ok(for cube there are 12 triangles and 36 indices)

Honestly at this point I have no idea what im doing wrong. Am i missing sth obvious?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming your vertex shader's cbuffer contains a WVP matrix, then you're transforming position from local model space to homogenous clip space. So let's also assume the rasterizer (and pixel shader) correctly identifies the vertex output as the SV_Position.

Comment: I've had this exact same problem where Assimp's model viewer correctly displays a mesh but I couldn't render it correctly in my D3D pipeline. That's a big hint. In my case I discovered the mesh vertex structure exported from Blender was different to my input layout and vertex structures. Try to match these structures for your testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured it out. The issue was that in some other file i already defined structure named Vertex. That structure contained also uv's so ultimately my vertex buffer ended up being a mess. Silly mistake.

Comment: Good work @K377v.  We've all made those silly mistakes and solving them ourselves is a good feeling and a great way to learn and gain experience.